# No image displayed with Header('Content-type: image/png')

Tags: php, mysql

I am having hard time displaying an image pulled out of a database using header('content-type:image/png'), it's returning an empty image and when I check the inspect element the img src name display the name of the php script, can anyone help please?

Here is part of the viewimage.php script attached with the img src

```
    $data = "SELECT fimgupload1_1 FROM controlpanel1";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection,$data);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    {
    $imgData = $row['fimgupload1_1'];
    }
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    echo $imgData;
    ?>
```

Comment: Just so we're clear, is fimgupload1_1 the image or a path to the image?

Comment: well 'fimupload1_1' is actually the column that contains the image name in mysql database.

Comment: Thanks for you help and sorry about being away from my desk and not able to respond quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `readfile` or `file_get_contents` if `$row['fimgupload1_1']` is path to your file

```
$data = "SELECT fimgupload1_1 FROM controlpanel1";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection,$data);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
$imgData = $row['fimgupload1_1'];
}
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo readfile($imgData);
```